# Meteor show and hide templates

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to find the meteor way to show and hide templates. Eg if the home button is clicked the home template is shown and all others hidden. I understand this is possible with session variables or dependencies but can't get either working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to achieve by using the `Session` variable, but you probably want to use the [iron router package](http://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) instead.

The following is a solution using the `Session` variable:

```html
<body>
    {{#if isPage 'home'}}
        {{> home}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if isPage 'about'}}
        {{> about}}
    {{/if}}
    <ul>
        <li><button class="clickChangesPage" data-page='home'>Home</button></li>
        <li><button class="clickChangesPage" data-page='about'>About</button></li>
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="home">
    <p>Home!</p>
</template>

<template name="about">
    <p>About!</p>
</template>
```

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){

    Session.setDefault('page', 'home');

    UI.body.helpers({
        isPage: function(page){
            return Session.equals('page', page)
        }
    })

    UI.body.events({
        'click .clickChangesPage': function(event, template){
            Session.set('page', event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-page'))
        }
    })

}
```

**Update 2 Mars 2016**

As pointed out in a comment, using `Template.dynamic` is a better solution. Here's the code using that one:

```html
<body>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=currentPage}}
    <ul>
        <li><button class="clickChangesPage" data-page='home'>Home</button></li>
        <li><button class="clickChangesPage" data-page='about'>About</button></li>
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="home">
    <p>Home!</p>
</template>

<template name="about">
    <p>About!</p>
</template>
```

```js
if(Meteor.isClient){

    Session.setDefault('page', 'home');

    Template.body.helpers({
        currentPage: function(page){
            return Session.get('page')
        }
    })

    Template.body.events({
        'click .clickChangesPage': function(event, template){
            Session.set('page', event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-page'))
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks I don't know it was possible via iron router so will look at that. Can you give any examples of doing it with session variables?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the quick response and I hope this helps others setting out with meteor. Stackoverflow save the day again :-)

Comment: Is this answer still relevant in 2016? Or should I better go for [{{> Template.dynamic template=currentPage}}](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-without-router/6511/7)?

Comment: @Edgar, yea, today that would be a better solution. I've updated my post accordingly. Also note that the `UI` object has been merged into the `Template` object.